# How to run a command every time git bash is started

Tags: git, terminal, git-bash

I have a question. But I don't even know how to explain you, but also to myself. But i will try to explain which is my problem. :(

Firstly, every time when I restart my computer I want to save in terminal auto this `export PS1="\e[0;31m\u\e[m\e[0;93m \W\e[m "`. To be more precise in "Git bash" Windows 10. Because i don't want to see each time in my terminal "Git Bash" this long string `Nicolai Cushnir@DESKTOP-HIVVKCH MINGW64 ~ $`. Yesterday I was tormented all day but did not understand how to do it.

Comment: Did the solution below work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Create a `.bashrc` file if it does not exist and then write the export command to it:

```
$ if [ ! -f ~/.bashrc ]; then touch ~/.bashrc; fi
$ echo 'export PS1="\e[0;31m\u\e[m\e[0;93m \W\e[m "' > ~/.bashrc
```

you might see this message the next time you start `git bash`:

> WARNING: Found ~/.bashrc but no ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login or
> ~/.profile.
>
> This looks like an incorrect setup. A ~/.bash_profile that loads
> ~/.bashrc will be created for you.

but that's ok and it just means `git bash` took care of a few things for you.